# Dynamic Linq to SQL with dynamic Entity objects and relationed attributes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic

Environment:

- VS2012 Professional;
- IIS 8;
- Windows 7 Professional;
- Oracle 11g;

Settings:

- C# 4.0;
- Entity Framework 4.1;
- Linq;
- MVC4 API;
- Using Dynamic Library from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx;

Goal:

- Dynamically define a LINQ using string parameters returning the result assigned to an object of EF.

Tries:

(Some printscreen source code)

[image]

[image]

Blocked by:

Was achieved the primary goal of making a dynamic query including its attributes referring to other objects of the EF. But we could not convert IQueryable result to a concrete object of EF.

How could I convert or cast my IQueryable to an dynamic IEnum or List of Entity Object or even a simple Dataset?

Thank you guys,

Paes, Andrew

Comment: "LINQ To SQL" is a separate product which predates EF. Be careful not to confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the result to IEnumberable firstly by calling AsEnumerable() on your resultSet.

Comment: I have tried like this, but my "Select" of my Dynamics Library returns just some types:

- AsNoTracking;
- AsParallel;
- AsQueryable (again);

Doesn't returns a AsEnumerable.

When I tried this I receive the error that You can see on last print screen.

I don't how to go now.

Thnaks J.W,

Paes, Andrew

Comment: Can you project into an anonymous type first, then project into your real business entities.